# Cordova - FileSystem - why so many path alternatives?

Tags: cordova, html5-filesystem, cordova-plugins

I am just looking through the Cordova source code to try and figure something out, and there are currently *six* alternate methods/properties to access the path of a file.

Currently (running using iOS), there is:

```
// Properties
file.fullPath; // file:///full/path/syntax/file
file.nativeURL; // file:///full/path/syntax/file

// Method(s)
file.toInternalURL(); // formats the file.fullPath into a cdvfile://localhost/persisten/file.
file.toURL(); // if file.nativeURL is set, uses file.nativeURL, otherwise use file.toInternalURL() or file.fullPath.

// Deprecated method(s)
file.toURI(); // deprecated - calls file.toURL();
file.toNativeURL() // deprecated - calls file.toURL();
```

I understand two are deprecated - which both point to `file.toURL()` - so I can ignore them and focus on just four methods.

But what is the difference between `file.fullPath` and `file.nativeURL` - they are exactly the same? They are both properties on the file object - both publicly accessible.

As far as I can tell, `file.toURL()` uses both of these - first `file.nativeURL` if not that, then `file.toInternalURL()` or failing that, then `file.fullPath`.

Then finally, `file.toNativeURL()` returns a `cdvfile://` formatted location.

So, most methods point to the `file.nativeURL` property. Is `file.toURL()` the method to use since it handles all instances? If so, then what on earth is `cdvfile://`?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`file.fullPath` is a part of the spec, and should actually look like: `/path/relative/to/my/root`. If you're seeing that it has `file:///`, then that's a bug.

`file.nativeURL` is meant to be an implementation detail. But sadly, it's not obviously marked as such. It's not a part of the spec, and doesn't exist on other platforms.

`file.toURL()` is likely what you want. It's a part of the spec, gives you a URL that can be passed to `resolveLocalFileSystemURL`, and has fewer gotchas compared to `cdvfile:` URLs.

`file.toInternalURL()` is not a part of the spec, but it a Cordova-specific extension. I don't think it would ever be a useful thing to use.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - when written, I was using Cordova 3.3.0; I have not upgraded currently but I will do and confirm whether this is still the case for iOS.